# Synchronize Coordinate System in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, australia

I have a map created in ArcGIS Pro ver 2, on the map the area of interest on the Layout Frame has a coordinate system of GDA94 MGA Zone 56.

On the Content Pane, the Map Grid is in MGA Zone 55 and the Map Frame is in MGA Zone 55.

How do I dynamically change or synchronize the MAP GRID MGA Zone 55 and the Map Frame Zone 55 to Layout Frame which has coordinate of MGA Zone 56?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [Project](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/project.htm) tool to change the projection to GDA94 MGA Zone 56. You can import it from your Map Frame or search for "EPSG:28356."

If the dataset does not have a projection already, then use the [Define Projection](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/define-projection.htm) tool. I'm using a newer version of Pro, but I'm sure it's similar

[image]

More helpful documentation: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/properties/specify-a-coordinate-system.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_0D8222787995420AA2B773987E3FEB83

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jacob, I will try your solution and let you know how I progress.

Comment: Hi Jacob, I thank you for your effort in finding a solution to my question, but it didn't work. The scenario is about the Map Frame and the Layout Frame coordinate system to dynamically synchronize.

Comment: @Soc Can you explain in detail what you mean by synchronizing the coordinate systems? What exactly are you trying to achieve and what did my proposed answer accomplish, if anything?

Comment: Hi Jacob,  The map I created has coordinate of GDA94 MGA Zone 56 .  But on the “Layers Map Frame”, the current grid coordinate is in MGA Zone 55 as well as on the “Content Pane”.  I wanted to dynamically synchronize these coordinate base from the area of interest on the Map window (map series).

Comment: And have you tried adjusting both the Map Frame and Layers’ coordinate systems?

Comment: Hi Jacob ...Yes I have adjusted the Map Frame and the Layers Grid Coordinates system manually.  Any idea to make this process dynamically or automated when the area of interest on the map is in different projection ?

Comment: If the area in question belongs to a different data source, then it may be possible to write a python script or other tool to accomplish this. For example, you can use the Projections & Transformations toolset to return a specific layer's spatial reference, which can be applied as an input parameter. First, you can use arcpy.Describe(<layer>).spatialReference to retrieve the spatial reference, then you can use arcpy.env.outputCoordinateSystem to apply that projection to the environment settings. But I'm unsure how you could then transfer that into the actual Map properties.

Comment: However, if the same data source/layer had differen't projections throughout it, the software would have to be re-engineered via the .NET SDK (https://developers.arcgis.com/net/latest/ios/guide/spatial-references.htm). In addition, Pro has this neat tool too you can use to create a spatial reference: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/create-spatial-reference.htm